# Google Tag Manager doesn't fire event trigger

Tags: google-tag-manager, gdprconsentform

we have an issue with a trigger on GTM. We have a "checkout" event that triggers several checkout tags (Universal Analytics, Facebook, GA4, etc.). The event is working fine: when we go to the checkout page we see from the GTM debugger the condition "checkout  equals checkout" that triggers the tags.

But, to be compliant with GDPR, we are implementing a trigger that blocks the tags to be fired if the cookie doesn't contain explicit acceptance. In the image, you can see that the condition is correctly met with "xxxxxxxxxx (cookie values)    does not contain "5":true".

Anyway, GTM also adds another condition on his own: "checkout equals gtm.js". We did not add this condition, that is clearly not met and then the trigger doesn't stop the tags to be fired, as it was supposed to to because of the the "xxxxxxxxxx does not contain "5":true" condition.

How can we solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWY4K.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your exception trigger is of type `Page View` in combination with the custom condition.
Meanwhile, your actual trigger is probably of type `Custom Event`, therefore, the exception trigger will never fire, even if your GDPR condition is true.
(`checkout` will never be equal to `gtm.js`)

To solve this, you have to change your blocking trigger `cookie.purpose 5 - Targeting - Not accepted` to type `Custom Event` and set the *Event Name* to `.*` and check `Use regex matching`.

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly! Can I ask you how this actually works, since I don't understand it:  "set the Event Name to .* and check Use regex matching"? Thank you again!

Comment: Good to hear! `.*` ist a regular expression that matches any character (`.`) between zero and unlimited times (`*`), hence the exception trigger triggers on *every event*. By adding the additional condition (cookie check), it triggers on *every event* when at the same time no consent was given, which is exactly what you want in this case.

Comment: Where do I change the blocking trigger? I am not able to find the event name edit feature anywhere.